# Is there a particular script to install fsl

Tags: python, conda, xquartz, fslab

This script is what I got from Google. Do I run them in quarts or IDLE?

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals

import functools      as ft
import os.path        as op
import subprocess     as sp
import textwrap       as tw
import                   argparse
import                   contextlib
import                   datetime
import                   fnmatch
import                   getpass
import                   hashlib
import                   json
import                   logging
import                   os
import                   platform
import                   pwd
import                   readline
import                   shlex
import                   shutil
import                   ssl
import                   sys
import                   tempfile
import                   threading
import                   time
import                   traceback

try:                
    import urllib.request as urlrequest
except ImportError:
    import urllib         as urlrequest


try:                
    import urllib.parse as urlparse
except ImportError: 
    import                 urlparse

try:                
    import queue
except ImportError: 
    import Queue as queue


PYVER = sys.version_info[:2]


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: is this what you want? `python -m pip install fslpy`?

Comment: You run that anywhere that runs Python (like `python x.py` at the command line), but that script doesn't do anything.  That's just a starter template.

Comment: Got it @TimRoberts